# Does a db:migrate on Heroku alter the production database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I'm working with a small app on Heroku and I'm wondering if a `heroku run rake db:migrate` will affect the production database. Any thoughts?

I tried `heroku db:pull` but the pull stopped midway (not to mention that it screwed up my local db):

```
Schema:         60% |====================================================================================                                                        | ETA:  00:00:16
Saving session to pull_201207010723.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 503
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <style type="text/css">
        html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
        iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
      </style>
    <title>Application Error</title></head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
        <p>Application Error</p>
      </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Additional notes:** local development db is sqlite3 and production db (by Heroku standard is postgresql). The devel db was like that by default and I couldn't find a nice tutorial to convert to postgresql.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm thinking this is related... See issue and comment: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/422#issuecomment-6698934

Comment: Without any change to my environment this started working today. Does anyone know of Heroku addressing this? I'd love to know more about the problem...

Answer (score 2):

Running `heroku run rake db:migrate` will indeed alter your database on Heroku -- so it will change your production database.